# NUMPY: Covariance Matrix of nested lists

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, covariance, nested-lists

This might have a dead simple answer, but I just cannot fathom it.
How would I go about finding the covariance matrix for nested lists?
To exemplify:

```
list = [[list1],[list2],[list3],...,[listn]]
```

I would like to find the covariance matrix for all of the elements of list.
I currently have a list containing 98 nested lists between which I need to find
the covariance matrix.
Thank you.

Comment: Just do `numpy.cov(my_lists)`.

Comment: Yes that would be my original line of thought however when i run: np.cov([[list1],[list2],[list3],...,[listn]]) i get a "ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence." and typing out the index for each list is not an option since the number of lists inside the main list for the covariance may change and is rather large for such "manual" approach.

Comment: Which version of numpy were you using back then? This works in v 1.13.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only plausible solution I came up with was the following:

```
covar = [[np.cov(frames[n], frames[i])[0][1] for n in range(len(frames))] for i in range(len(frames))]
```

the variable frames is the list where the other lists containing the data are nested. 
 Someone please do correct me if my solution is lame.
Luis

Edit 1: I know I should have set a variable containing range(len(frames)) but for clarity
purposes I chose not to.

Edit 2: I just found a piece of code that solved my problem!

```
frames = np.asarray(frames)
covar = np.cov(frames)
```

A lot faster... And cleaner too!